# Use case of integral of differential forms on "chains"

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I'm studying Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds. There the integration of $k$-forms on $k$-chains is defined and Stokes' theorem on chains is also proved, but they are never used for other theorems. I also cannot imagine where to use it in applications or maths. Why do we need to define $k$-chains? Where can I use it?

A related question, but not answered, is here:

[What's the advantage of defining the integral of a $k$-form over a $k$-chain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737591/whats-the-advantage-of-defining-the-integral-of-a-k-form-over-a-k-chain)

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726603/on-the-meaning-of-formal-sums-of-k-cubes-i-e-k-chains-in-integration-on-m

Comment: @Rohan Here is a copy of a part of the comment you pointed: [the point is to think of splitting up a "region" as a union of things that can be reasonably parametrized by cubes so as to split the integral over the "region" into manageable pieces.] However, I cannot get the point. We don't need chains to split the integral over the "region" into manageable pieces. For example, authors mentioned in the question I linked don't use chains at all, but they can do split integrals. Even Spivak defines chains but never use them. What is the advantage of using chains?